# Given the geometric mean is it possible to find the GP series?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

I have an equation (j+1)^2=(i+1)(k+1) . I have the value of j and I need to find all possible i and k.

My real problem was given a string s='ccaccbbbaccccca' I need to find all sub-sequences 'abc' or 'cba'. Now let i,j,k be position of a,b and c respectively then I also need to make sure that (j+1)^2=(i+1)(k+1)

I was able to find all subsequences by finding j's and multiplying the number of a's before this position j and the number of c's after j'th position. Example s='aabcc' then j=2 and number of a's=2 and c's after j ='2' so the number of 'abc' is 4. similarly for 'cba' . So my method to check for satisfiability of the equation was to get the count of a's and c's and which ever is having a lesser count I collect their indices l1,l2,l3. I plug in the value of j and li and find the missing k/i then I check if the kth position holds a/c if it does I increment my count. But this solution seems to be taking a lot of time.

So I came to the realisation that it's futile to manually check by substituting 2 values and finding the third one. I have to somehow find the pairs (i,k)'s count directly . 
I then realized that the solution to this problem boils down to finding the number of unique pairs (i,k) for the equation (j+1)^2=(i+1)(k+1) such that i0 for some n. then all I need to do is take all the pairs (i,k) and check if String s[i]='a' and s[k]='c' But going through geometric mean properties I couldn't find any resources on how to find them directly. They always required atleast two values to find the other missing value.

Comment: However there was some typos, I found this an interesting question and nice application to find the closure of a language. I will use a word instead of string. Did you think of using the following algorithm: for a given word $w$ of finite length $n$ for finding the subsequence for example $abc$ put $I_a$ the list of positions where the letter $a$ appears in the word $w$ and respectively $I_b$ and $I_c$ for the letters $b$ and $c$. Now your questions becomes a combinatoric question how many elements in $(x,y,z)\in I_a\times I_b\times I_c$ has property $x<y<z$. Good luck.